# Android - How to keep a process alive a little longer

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-workmanager, foreground-service

I have an app which is heavily based on C++ (NDK), with it comes a lot of state which is non trivial to be put in a bundle or use some other method to persist it. The app allows users to modify photos etc, so the size of file in memory can get pretty big which can make the saving operation run a little longer (3-4 secs) than what Android would allow.

Previously, I had found that starting a foreground service in `onPause` allowed us to keep the process alive just long enough for us to carry our work. And even though Android-12's foreground service restrictions do allow foreground services to be run during the `onPause` transition, but I've discovered that this isn't true for all OEMs (specifically Samsung devices have lots of `ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException`).

So my question is, is there a way I can keep process alive just a little longer for the saving operation to finish?

I've tried my luck with `WorkManager` when I read the `setExpedited` allowed the job to be run immediately (and on older devices this would just start a foreground service, so this seemed very similar to my previous approach but with added benefit of supporting newer devices). But I discovered that this isn't fast enough to escape the slaughter brought down on Android's UI thread.

PS: If it is relevant, all the saving is a simple disk I/O operation not a network one.

Comment: Start the foreground service when your save operation starts, rather than `onPause()`. I'm assuming that the save operation is occurring based on user input, so you would be in the foreground at the time.

Comment: @CommonsWare No, this is more of an auto-save operation. Users expect our app to autosave, even if they exit the app. Hence we do it in `onPause()`.

Comment: Start the foreground service when your Activity starts.  Send it a save command in onPause, which starts the saving process.  Since it was already started, it can process a new command.

Comment: @GabeSechan Does it mean that notification would be on for the entire duration? (since that is mandatory for a foreground service?).

Comment: Yes, it would.  If you're only taking 3-4 seconds it can also be a background service started when your app starts.  Background services get around 2 minutes after you leave the foreground to perform any work.

Comment: oh! I didn't know that! Do you have any resource which talks about the 2 minute limit?

Comment: @GabeSechan It seems that background service is only kept for as long as the activity is around? I have to block mainThread in MainActivity#onDestroy so the activity doesn't end before the saving has finished. Is this the case typically or it is my OEM being extra strict?

Comment: So far, as per my testing and observation on production app, a simple thread executor will be sufficient to do the job. As long as the task finished within N seconds (Not sure the exact number), seems like Android will not kill the Thread. No foreground service, or WorkManager required. Do you have other observations if using a simple Thread executor?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng IIRC, ChromeOS' Android runtime (ARC) kills app as soon as its activity does and they don't have any service running and I thought this may well happen in some OEM's implementation too. So using a foreground service was a good way to preserve it (especially since we could assume memory pressure being rather high)